# How to get 3d cube style for my div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want 3d style for this div. I don't have any idea how to do it.

```css
.cube{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#ff7700;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:95px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cube">3D Cube</div>
```

Comment: https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/cube.html
https://davidwalsh.name/css-cube

Comment: 6 upvotes ??? Really ????

Answer (score 3):

> https://davidwalsh.name/css-cube check out this may be this will help you

```css
body {
     margin-top: 125px;
 }

@-moz-keyframes spinningH {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to{
    -moz-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinningH {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes spinningH {
  from {
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to{
    -o-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes spinningH {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to{
    -ms-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spinningH {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to{
    transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

 #container {
  -webkit-perspective : 1000px;
  -moz-perspective    : 1000px;
  -o-perspective      : 1000px;
  -ms-perspective     : 1000px;
  perspective         : 1000px;

  -webkit-perspective-origin  : 50% 50%;
  -moz-perspective-origin     : 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin       : 50% 50%;
  -o-perspective-origin       : 50% 50%;
  -ms-perspective-origin      : 50% 50%;
  perspective-origin          : 50% 50%;
 }

.animate {
  -webkit-animation : spinningH 6s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation    : spinningH 6s infinite linear;
  -o-animation      : spinningH 6s infinite linear;
  -ms-animation     : spinningH 6s infinite linear;
  animation         : spinningH 6s infinite linear;
}

#cube {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;

  -webkit-transition  : -webkit-transform 2s linear;
  -moz-transition     : -moz-transform 2s linear;
  -o-transition       : -o-transform 2s linear;
  -ms-transition      : -ms-transform 2s linear;
  transition          : transform 2s linear;

  -webkit-transform-style : preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style    : preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style      : preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style     : preserve-3d;
  transform-style         : preserve-3d;
}

#cube>div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 360px;
  width: 360px;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-position:center center;
}

#cube div:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform : translateZ(200px);
  -moz-transform    : translateZ(200px);
  -o-transform      : translateZ(200px);
  -ms-transform     : translateZ(200px);
  transform         : translateZ(200px);
  background-color  : #2E272F;
  
  background-repeat : no-repeat;
}

#cube div:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform : rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  -moz-transform    : rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  -o-transform      : rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  -ms-transform     : rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform         : rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  background-color  : #2D3A4D;
 
  background-repeat : no-repeat;
}

#cube div:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform : rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
  -moz-transform    : rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
  -o-transform      : rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
  -ms-transform     : rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform         : rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
  background-color  : #2D1C12;
 
  background-repeat : no-repeat;
}

#cube div:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform : rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
  -moz-transform    : rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
  -o-transform      : rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
  -ms-transform     : rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform         : rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
  background-color  : #693C1F;
 
  background-repeat : no-repeat;
}

#cube div:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform : rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px) rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform    : rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px) rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform      : rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px) rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform     : rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px) rotate(180deg);
  transform         : rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px) rotate(180deg);
  background-color  : #955122;
 
  background-repeat :no-repeat;
}

#cube div:nth-child(6)  {
  -webkit-transform : rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  -moz-transform    : rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  -o-transform      : rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  -ms-transform     : rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform         : rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  background-color  : #E34C26;
  
  background-repeat :no-repeat;
  text-align:center;  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="cube" class="animate">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But It is Not Exactly i want style for only one div try once in this way

Answer (score 2):

```css
.scene {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 75px auto 0;
  perspective: 1200px;
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: example 10s linear infinite;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #9aa;
  background-color: rgba(32, 170, 151, 0.5);
  padding: 120px 0;
  font: 50px/1 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-150px);
}
.top {
  transform: translateY(-150px) rotateX(90deg);
}
.bottom {
  transform: translateY(150px) rotateX(90deg);
}
.front {
  transform: translateZ(150px);
}
.top, .bottom {
  background-color: rgba(105, 136, 190, 0.5)
}

@keyframes example {
  100% { transform: rotateX(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="side back">BACK</div>
    <div class="side top">TOP</div>
    <div class="side bottom">BOTTOM</div>
    <div class="side front">FRONT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But It is Not Exactly i want style for only one div try once in this way

Answer (score 1):

```css
div{
line-height:100px;
color:#600;
}
.e1{
 position:absolute;
 left:450px;
 top:250px;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:#00ffff;
 opacity:0.5;
 text-align:center;
}
.e2{
 position:absolute;
 left:450px;
 top:190px;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:red;
 -ms-transform: skewY(50deg);
 -webkit-transform: skewY(50deg);
 -moz-transform: skewY(50deg);
 z-index:-1;
 text-align:center;
 
}
.e3{
 position:absolute;
 left:350px;
 top:191px;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:yellow;
 -ms-transform: skewY(50deg);
 -webkit-transform: skewY(50deg);
 -moz-transform: skewY(50deg);
 opacity:0.9;
 z-index:-1;
 text-align:center;
 
}
.e4{
 position:absolute;
 left:408px;
 top:250px;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:green;
 -ms-transform: skewX(40deg);
 -webkit-transform: skewX(40deg);
 -moz-transform: skewX(40deg);
 z-index:-4;
 text-align:center;
 
}
.e5{
 position: absolute;
    left: 351px;
    top: 131px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: lightblue;
    -ms-transform: skewX(1deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(1deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(1deg);
    z-index: -5;
    text-align: center;
 
}
.e6{
 position: absolute;
    left: 399px;
    top: 131px;
    width: 102px;
    height: 119px;
    background: #75d55f;
    -ms-transform: skewX(40deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(40deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(40deg);
    z-index: 0;
    text-align: center;
 opacity:0.5;
 
 
}
```

```html
<div class="e1">1</div>
   <div class="e2">2</div>
   <div class="e3">3</div>
   <div class="e4">4</div>
   <div class="e5">5</div>
   <div class="e6">6</div>
```

Comment: But It is Not Exactly i want style for only one div try once in this way